# In Python, how do you generate permutations of an array where you only have one element from each column and row?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, permutation

For example:

Say you have the following array:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

and you want to generate this array:

```
[1,5,9]
[1,6,8]
[4,2,9]
[4,8,3]
[7,2,6]
[7,5,3]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import itertools

A=[[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]]

for P in itertools.permutations(range(len(A))):
    print [A[p][i] for i,p in enumerate(P)]
```

Prints:

```
[1, 5, 9]
[1, 8, 6]
[4, 2, 9]
[4, 8, 3]
[7, 2, 6]
[7, 5, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Could someone explain how it works exactly?

Comment: For each column i, it chooses a row p.  The i's are all unique because they are 0,1,2,...  The p's are all unique because they come from a permutation.  itertools.permutations generates all the permutations so this iterates through all choices.